# Get the url from mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, visual-c++, firefox-addon, mozilla, xpcom

I am a newbie to XPCOM and mozilla. 
My requirement is to get the **tab title and the url associated in firefox browser** using c++ in windows. Can I have a C++ application that can use one of XPCOM interface function's to get this data out of firefox.

Comment: Yes its possible, I don't know much about C++ extensions though. Is it possible for you to make a JS extension?

Comment: Thanks, for the reply Noitidart, Though I am suppose to do it with a c++ application but if it can be done through a js extension then I am fine with it. I also think there is a way for a js extension to comunicate with a c++ native application. But I have no idea about creating a js extension let alone accomplising the aforesaid task using it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice for js extenisons - I looked into how to create an extensions and was looking into different Global objects that I can use for my cause..and happened to find the following piece of code -                                        

CODE :
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
// Listen for tab content loads.
tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  console.log('url and title",  tab.title, tab.url);
});

Comment: Is it possible for a c++ application to comunicate with a js extension plugged in with mozilla firefox?

Comment: JS can talk to C - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes and the SO help section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsctypes

Comment: Noitidart , though using extension I am able to get the job done period. but is it possible to do with any other way excluding the use of an extension.Since automating IE using COM and interfaces like  IWebBrowser2 and others can be written in a c++ console applicaton.  So since for automating IE we dont require a IE extension (i guess...), why are we using extension for mozilla firefox?